# Advantages of using 64-bit word size over 32-bit word size

Tags: algorithm-design, sha-2

I'm learning about cryptographic hash functions and I have some questions about SHA-2.

SHA-256 uses 8 32-bit words. SHA-512 uses 8 64-bit words.

Is there a specific reason why SHA-512 uses 64-bit words? Why not 16 32-bit words?

And if 64-bit words have their advantages over 32-bit words. Why doesn't SHA-256 use 4 64-bit words?

Comment: It's not used much, but NIST has put out a revision of the SHA-2 docuemnt to specify SHA-512/256 and SHA-512/224 - which are basically SHA-512 cut down to the right bit size (and different internal constants, to make the calculations differ). On 32 bit machines (or, e.g. in smart cards, augmented 8 or 16 bit machines) SHA-256 is faster, due to the smaller state size etc. So well, they kind of released a 64 bit version of SHA-256, only more secure, for 64 bit optimized processors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reason of using 64-bit word size over 32-bit word size is speed, on CPUs that manipulate words sequentially. Doubling the word size can hope to about double the number of elementary bitwise operations performed in a given amount of time, on a 64-bit CPU like one using the [AMD64 instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64).

As an aside, for constant number of words in the internal state of a an algorithm (like a hash), the number of bits in the state is twice as large, which can improve the cryptographic resistance (if other conditions apply; in particular, at least twice as many bit operations); and allows a larger result.

Accordingly, for large input, SHA-512 is typically faster than SHA-256 on the same 64-bit CPU, even though SHA-512 uses 25% more rounds, and has a state with twice more bits, making it arguably safer.

Update per [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/40344/555#comment92180_40345): word size has no direct impact on security. As an illustration, it is possible to reformulate SHA-512 as using 32-bit words, with identical result thus security; compilers for 32-bit CPUs do this automatically.

Comment: Thanks! But generally speaking hash functions with 64-bit word size are more secure than those with 32-bit word size right? That's what it says [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Comparison_of_SHA_functions) (security  in bits).